# terminal returns "command not found" on "npm run dev" from Next.js application created through Vercel

Tags: github, next.js, vercel

So I used Vercel to start my next.js project. The project resides on in a repository on GitHub. I cloned the GitHub repository to my computer and when I try to run

`"npm run dev"`

I get a

> "command not found error"

Any thoughts on why this may be? I think I'm in the right directory.

[Screenshot of nextJS project in VsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88YkE.png)

I tried looking online to see if I was in the right directory, and it looks like I am.

Comment: what does it log, if you `npm --version`

Comment: npm --version 8.15.0

Comment: go to package.json and check the `scripts` property. if it includes `dev`

Comment: Yes it does include dev, Heres the script section in package.json:       "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },

Comment: maybe you are in the same directory as `package.json`. if you write `ls` on terminal, it will list of files and folders inside the current directory. do you see `package.json`

Comment: Yes sir I do see it.

Comment: Oh. did you install the packages. `npm install`

Comment: Oh my gosh that worked. I apologize for my vast ignorance. I know I'm a stranger to you but I'm very appreciative for you helping me.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Yilmaz, he figured it out.

make sure to run `npm install` in your terminal. Make sure you are in the same directory as where your `package.json` file is.